# Polymer 1.x: How to align buttons and button text inside <paper-toolbar>?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, custom-element

[In this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/nimoyomali/1/edit?html,output) I need to:

- align the two buttons in the toolbar flush with the right edge of the viewport (right justify) and
- vertically align the text to the middle of the buttons

> **Please provide a working JSBin example of how to do that.**

#### Code

http://jsbin.com/nimoyomali/1/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="http://polygit.org/polymer:+v1.1.0/components/">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html">
</head>

<body class="fullbleed vertical layout">
  <paper-drawer-panel class="flex">
    <paper-header-panel drawer>
      <paper-toolbar>
        <div>Logo</div>
      </paper-toolbar>
      <div>Drawer content...</div>
    </paper-header-panel>
    <paper-header-panel main class="flex seamed">
      <paper-toolbar class="seamed">
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div>App Name</div>
                <span class="flex"></span>
                <paper-button style="background:white;
                                    color:black;
                                    height:100%;
                                    border-radius:0px;
                                    margin:0;
                                    border-left:solid 1px black;"
                >Button 1</paper-button>
                <paper-button style="background:white;
                                    color: black;
                                    height: 100%;
                                    border-radius: 0px;
                                    margin: 0;
                                    border-left: 1px solid black;
                                    vertical-align: middle;"
                >Button 2</paper-button>
          </paper-toolbar>
      <div>Main content...</div>
    </paper-header-panel>
  </paper-drawer-panel>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To center the text within the `paper-button`, you can try -

```
paper-button {
  --paper-button: {
    @apply(--layout-vertical);
    @apply(--layout-center-center);
  };
}
```

The `paper-toolbar` has a default left and right padding of `16px`. The easiest way to get rid of it is to apply a `-16px` right margin to the right button.

See this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/pideyecixa/edit?html,output) for a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

[And here is the JSbin with the margin applied](http://jsbin.com/vikazaqedu/3/edit?html,output).

#### Code

http://jsbin.com/vikazaqedu/3/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="http://polygit.org/polymer:+v1.1.0/components/">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">

  <style is="custom-style">
    paper-button {
      --paper-button: {
        @apply(--layout-vertical);
        @apply(--layout-center-center);
      };

      background:white;
      color:black;
      height:100%;
      border-radius:0;      
      border-left:solid 1px black;
      margin:0;
    }

    paper-button.last {
      margin: 0 -16px 0 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="fullbleed vertical layout">
  <paper-drawer-panel class="flex">
    <paper-header-panel drawer>
      <paper-toolbar>
        <div>Logo</div>
      </paper-toolbar>
      <div>Drawer content...</div>
    </paper-header-panel>
    <paper-header-panel main class="flex seamed">
      <paper-toolbar class="seamed">
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div>App Name</div>
        <span class="flex"></span>

        <paper-button>Button 1</paper-button>     
        <paper-button class="last">Button 2</paper-button>

      </paper-toolbar>
      <div>Main content...</div>
    </paper-header-panel>
  </paper-drawer-panel>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oops I think I accidentally changed the jsbin as I was experimenting stuff. Just reversed it so the margin is applied again... Just so you know the `paper-toolbar` css should be removed.

Comment: @JustinXL: Got it. Thanks for the follow up. I deleted the CSS and updated the link.